# Php array cache

Tags: php, arrays, caching

I have a big database, and I get data from there and stored in an array. I am working in this data, but I don't want to get every time this data from the database, I want to cache it, it's enought for me to get each 5 minutes. How could I cache an array?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You say database, but your tags don't specify one. If it's MySQL - there is [SELECT SQL_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html) mode

Comment: your question about Php array cache? And in your details you are talking about the database caches .can you give more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to cache data. Have a look at memcache as a way to store data in server memory between PHP requests.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can install APC cache. 
It uses internal memory of your server.

After you can set array with `apc_store('key_name', serialize($array))` and fetch with `apc_fetch('key_name')`

Also you can define expiration time for caches.

Its very easy and fast.

Comment: which one is better Alternative PHP Cache and Memcache?

Comment: Memcache can be distributable between servers. But it needs more dependency and it works over TCP port. This means you have extra TCP overhead. APC cannot be  distributable but it not uses TCP and not having any dependency.

Comment: It's look very good, could you write here an example which is depending from time.(1 minit cache time). Thanks.

Comment: apc_store(key, value, 60)  -- 60 means 1 minute.